# Lot's of data was tripled in nop commerce, customer roles, message templates, etc

Tags: nopcommerce

a client of ours was messing around with the admin side of nopcommerce, and she found a lot of the data seems to have tripled.  After lot's of searching around, I can't seem to find anyone who has had a similar issue.

One thing I noticed when initially looking at this, was that there were 3 languages (all English).  Removing 2 of these didn't give any errors, but also didn't help with the tripled data.  Up until now, that was my best guess as to what could be going wrong.

Has anyone else experienced anything like this, or have a greater knowledge of nopCommerce that might have an idea what is going wrong?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOGSR.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZUAf.png

Comment: which data are rtipled? can you give some proper example

Comment: Yea, I'm sorry, there are a couple links to screenshots.  But for instance, when adding a new customer, there is an option to select from Administrator, Guest, Registered, etc... however this option exists 3 times for each of them.

Answer (score 1):

Problem you installed this nopcommerce, using the wizard, many times. When you did that some records are duplacaded, because the wizard doesn`t treat it.

I've the same problem and o solve that removing it directly in database...